# Expand Linux partition after creating a vsphere_virtual_machine resource with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am utilizing Terraform's vsphere_virtual_machine resource to clone virtual machines from a template. The Disk sub-resource (required for each disk in the template) allows you to grow the size of a disk during provisioning. I am looking for suggestions on how to then automatically expand space from the Operating System's perspective (partition, logical volume, file system). I currently do this manually with tools like fdisk, lvextend, etc. but would like to automate it in code. If this is outside the scope of Terraform, are there other strategies or automation tools that would better accomplish this task (e.g. a configuration management tool like Chef)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remote_exec` provisioner to accomplish this:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host = "${var.ip}"
      user = "ubuntu"
      password = "${var.VP}"
  }

    inline = [
      "echo ${var.VP} | sudo -S growpart /dev/sda 2",
      "sudo growpart /dev/sda 5",
      "sudo pvresize /dev/sda5",
      "sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--base--vg-root",
      "sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--base--vg-root"
    ]
  }
```

Your command will vary slightly depending on the OS and the partition labels, but the gist is the same.

And I have no clue why I have to `growpart /dev/sda 2` before `growpart /dev/sda 5` but I do. This worked for an Ubuntu 16.04 template on VMWare ESXI.

Answer (score 0):

> And I have no clue why I have to `growpart /dev/sda 2` before `growpart /dev/sda 5` but I do.

If you run `fdisk -l` you will see partition 5 is an LVM that starts and ends within partition 2 that is an Extended. So partition 2 must first be grown before partition 5 can be grown.